# Execute multiple TestNG suites in parallel

Tags: java, maven, parallel-processing, testng

I've seen documentation that says [you can run TestNG classes/methods/both in parallel](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/testng.html#Running_tests_in_parallel). I was curious if there is some configuration (presumably in the maven-surefire-plugin in the pom) where we could something to the effect of

```
<plugin>
 <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
 <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
 <configuration>
  <parallel>suites</parallel>
 </configuration>
</plugin>
```

If not, are there any clever workarounds to achieve something similar?

Ex:if I have 5 suites (suite1.xml, suite2.xml, suite3.xml etc)

Each of these suites contains 3 classes (suite1 : class1a, class1b, class1c; suite2 : class2a, class2b, etc)

I could technically annotate class1a, class1b, and class1c as a "Group1" group. Then I could do something similar for "Group2" and "Group3". Could I then go ahead try to execute these *groups* in parallel (achieving a similar effect as running the suites in parallel)?

Alternatively, is there a way to partition the suites in some way to run on different JVM processes [by forking the tests](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/fork-options-and-parallel-execution.html)?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? By testng does not support execution  by groups. But you could have defined tests from different groups in different suite xmls.

Comment: My objective is simple. I have 50 decoupled suites that currently execute sequentially. I would like these to execute in parallel. The current testNG framework does NOT recognize parallelism at the suite level via the maven surefire plugin config (but it does at the class/method level). So my question is, how can I reach a state where I'm running suites in parallel via a workaround.

Comment: It actually does. See http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/fork-options-and-parallel-execution.html

The most obvious one is by using the parallel parameter. The possible values depend on the test provider used. For JUnit 4.7 and onwards, this may be methods, classes, both, **suites**, **suitesAndClasses**, **suitesAndMethods**, classesAndMethods, all. As of surefire 2.16, the value "both" is deprecated but it still can be used and behaves same as classesAndMethods.

Comment: I know that this is allowed for jUnit (the last line in my question references the same link as yours). But can you point me to documentation that explicitly states that it is allowed in TestNG?

Comment: https://groups.google.com/d/forum/testng-users is your best bet.